# New RAID1+0 in P2000 storage

Tags: storage, hp, storage-area-network, hp-storageworks

I have P2000 SAS storage with RAID6 configured on 8 disks 1TB 7k2rpm. I want to add RAID1+0 with 4 SAS15K 300GB.

The question is, does this storage support this setup? Should it work without any difficulties with 2 RAID types? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This works.

In HP P2000 language, ***vdisk*** is the term that represents a grouping of like-disks. You can have a vdisk comprised of one drive type and another of a different drive type in the same enclosure. This sounds like you have a 12-bay enclosure. If you were using a 24-bay enclosure, the maximum number of drives in a single vdisk is 16... Not an issue in your case...

Here's the [P2000 provisioning guide](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02520791/c02520791.pdf) for your reference.